# onkeydown attribute not working in FireFox 113

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I'm creating an interactive SVG map and I need the elements to all be accessible via keyboard navigation. I added an onkeydown attribute to the <g> tag and it calls a function that loads an unordered list related to the county on the map that is currently focused via `tabindex="0"`. Everything works fine in Chrome and Edge, but it does not work in Firefox. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I've looked online and everything seems to indicate that it should work in Firefox.

```js
const loadList = (item) => console.log(item);
function enterPress(event, item) {
  if (event.key == "Enter") {
    loadList(item);
  } else {}
}
```

```html
<g id="county" tabindex="0" onkeydown="enterPress(event, 'Clarendon')" onclick="loadList('Clarendon')">
  <title>Clarendon</title>
  <path d="M 467.13 316.21 473.2 310.11 474.26 306.22 476.31 302.12 480.36 302.25 481.2 297.45 484.26 297.28 485.11 300.11 483.71 302.55 490.79 301.78 489.92 295.54 489.87 291.35 510.85 287.54 513.47 283.96 523.43 276.91 533.36 270.89 535.67 270.71 546.49 263.17 555.76 257.4 560.02 255.12 563.84 265.52 564.92 267.15 572.16 266.47 576.64 267.18 570.16 280.55 567.21 282.16 565.31 282.28 556.87 290.81 560.5 300.03 557.39 303.48 552.89 315.23 547.41 327.93 539.64 345.09 535.64 344.02 535.36 345.85 531.24 348.82 534.62 351.7 532.59 352.84 531.91 354.54 527.33 354.83 526.43 353.64 524.05 355.65 519.54 355.87 515.08 354.59 511.91 357.09 510.42 355.29 505.95 356.68 502.59 358.49 497.4 358.68 490.8 355.63 490.14 354.68 483.54 349.26 484.03 347.19 482.61 344.3 478.35 341.67 478.42 339.61 480.82 340.24 481.71 336.79 480.97 335.71 478.21 336.69 477.15 334.34 475.41 332.92 473.53 333.24 472.22 330.95 470.34 330.01 472.32 326.63 469.56 325.49 469.24 321.67 466.09 319.39 467.94 318.04 467.13 316.21 Z"
    id="Clarendon" fill="#b3c4db" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="500" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" fill="blue" text-anchor="middle">Clarendon</text>
</g>
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my Firefox on OSX. I made a snippet

Comment: @mplungjan I believe OP might be missing the `svg` tag, seems like it doesn't work with it.

Comment: Ah, well spotted but it still works :)

Comment: Ah yes so this is just a small portion of the svg. If I had included the entire svg it would have been too big to post here. The full project is online here: https://libguides.furman.edu/sc-newspapers

Comment: @milesdame I can reproduce your problem only if the `g` tag is inside an SVG, please [edit] your question to provide a [mre]